# How to reduce the size of windows OS Iso file?

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd, iso-image, compression, 7-zip

I have an Iso file of windows 8.1 pro with December '14 updates. The problem is the file is too big to be burned on a normal 4.7GB DVD , its around 4.8. Now is it possible to remove a few updates so that i can make a bootable windows DVD.

Or is there any other alternative so that i can store this on DVD.

I tried compressing it to .uif and .7z format but even though the size reduces the numerous ripping softwares i tried using said this file was too big even though the windows properties of this compressed file says its less than 4.7 gb

Comment: mount the WIM and run **DISM /Image:C:\mount /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase** to cleanup the WIM. It removes older and replaced updates.

Comment: See someone boot off off a 1.4MB floppy disk, run windows, note pad, surf the web etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_VlI6IBEJ0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed: Compression is not going to work.
You can compress the ISO file however you want when it sits on your harddisk, but the data is always written UNCOMPRESSED to the DVD. The DVD format doesn't support compression on the DVD in this way.

Modifying a pre-build ISO to take out some updates is possible but it is an arcane art.
Extremely complicated and you will need to have a very good understanding of how slipstreaming works.

Rolling your own ISO starting from a base Windows ISO and adding only the desired patches (and possibly some drivers) is MUCH easier and you can control the size of the resulting ISO with a lot less hassle.

Obviously you can burn to a dual-layer DVD. This will give you an effective capacity of 8.5 GB.

But:
Have you considered to make a bootable USB stick instead ? It is a lot faster to install Windows from USB.
A 8 GB USB stick costs about the same money as a couple of dual-layer DVDs and the USB can be re-used for something else after use.
(Also bear in mind that DVD drives are not really standard anymore in new computers. But they all have USB ports and can boot from a USB device.)

Comment: "Modifying a pre-build ISO to take out some updates is possible but it is an arcane art.
Extremely complicated and you will need to have a very good understanding of how slipstreaming works." -- When I used to do this to fit Windows XP images onto those little credit-card sized CDs, I found a tool that gave a very simple UI for picking and choosing what you wanted to include in the image (I can't remember what it was called, now, unfortunately).  Is there nothing like that available for more recent Windows versions?

Comment: ... Ah, hold on, it was "nLite", which @Amit's answer mentions...

Answer (score 2):

You can download ISO without updates from MSDN website where the size will be equal to 2GB of size and after installation of the OS you can install the upgrades.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use nlite or rt se7ven. These programs allows you to customize windows os. Here you can remove unwanted drivers(There will be plenty of drivers which your device dont have. Windows by default put all drivers for ease. Be aware of not removing controller device). Remove all the language packs, Feature you dont want like internet explorer, wmc, media feature, wall papers,softwares.
Expert peoples are able to make a 500mb win 7 os from these easy to use tools within an our.

Comment: How exactly; having used this program before, it's not that simple

Comment: Here's a review of se7ven; perhaps overly positive, but I expect it's useful to some power users of Win7:
http://lifehacker.com/5894838/customize-your-windows-installation-to-create-the-os-of-your-dreams

Comment: And it looks like the successor to nlite, NTLite, may even work well with Windows 10: http://www.intowindows.com/download-ntlite-for-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

The answer in 2020 that applies specifically to Windows 8.1 is to download an official ISO image from Microsoft. At the time of writing, the ISO file **will** fit on a standard, single-layer DVD. This is clearly going to be much simpler than compressing or trying to remove folders/files from an oversized ISO image. Steps:

1. Visit https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8ISO
2. From the three dropdown lists, choose your options
3. Burn the downloaded ISO file to DVD

Example choices:

- Select Edition - Windows 8.1
- Select Language - English
- Select 32-bit **Download size 2.98GB**
- Select 64-bit **Download size 4.02GB**

The ISO image should contain reasonably recent updates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you buy a [dual layer DVD](http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n:10967881,p_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin:2890480011), they are about twice as large and should be writeable by a regular DVD burner. Would that be big enough?

Comment: Actually, not all DVD burners are able to write dual layer discs.  The discs also cost about 20x as much as single layer discs, so a solution that doesn't involve needing them is definitely a better option where possible.

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that my answer relates to **Windows 10** not Windows 8.1. Using the [Windows 8.1 Media Creation Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=510815) with the command line options provided in this answer will **not** work; no command-line options exist in the 8.1 version of the MCT. Nevertheless, I believe my answer may be of value to a wider audience, beyond the original questioner, who may be asking themselves the same question of Windows 10.*

I just solved the problem of downloading an ISO image file of Windows 10 Professional 1909 x64 that will fit on a DVD5. I've yet to install Windows using it, but the resulting ISO file is well within the capacity limit of a DVD5 (`4,707,319,808 bytes`), weighing in at `4,271,374,336 bytes`. For comparison, the ISO image named `Win10_1909_English_x64.iso`, available for direct download from Microsoft's site, weighs in at `5,421,461,504 bytes`, and will not fit on a DVD5.

Steps:

1. Download `MediaCreationTool1909.exe` (or whatever version of this tool is current) from [Microsoft's site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
2. Logged into Windows with an Administrator account, open a `cmd` window, `chdir` to the directory where you downloaded `MediaCreationTool1909.exe`
3. Copy and paste the following line into the `cmd` window (adjust to taste):

   ```
   MediaCreationTool1909 /Download /Eula Accept /MediaLangCode en-GB /MediaArch x64 /MediaEdition Professional /Action CreateMedia
   ```
4. The GUI will launch and prompt you to choose which media to use (USB flash drive or ISO file). Choose ISO file.
5. The GUI will then prompt where you want to save the file; choose your desired location.
6. Wait for the download and ISO file generation to complete.

The key thing I found was that if I run `MediaCreationTool1909.exe` from Explorer — as most people would — then I do not see any other editions of Windows in the dropdown list, so I presume both Professional and Home editions are included in the resulting ISO Image file, bulking it up considerably. I'm running the tool on a Windows 7 Ultimate computer (not sure if that makes a difference).

[image: Screenshot of Media Creation Tool and missing editions]

It would be great if Microsoft documented the Media Creation Tool's command line options. The command line in step 3 was pieced together from [this page](https://kevinstreet.co.uk/tag/windows-10-1903/) and [this forum post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-download-windows-10-iso-file-post1383640.html#post1383640).

Comment: Unfortunately the author’s question was specifically about the Windows 8.1 ISO.  While Windows 8.1 had its own Media Creation Tool, I cannot personally indicate, if these commands worked on it also.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point. I've edited my answer so that it's clear it relates to Windows 10. I think there's still value in my answer, to a wider audience, esp. given Windows 7 will be EOL on 14-1-2019

Comment: Did not work for my MediaCreationTool20H2.exe. The final ISO was only about 10 MB smaller than the one created via GUI. I read some posts on the MS forum. MS official clearly states that the current iso images via media creation tool are not suitable for 4.7 GB DVDs. Users need to use either a USB drive or a Dual Layer DVD.

Comment: It does seem that the required command line arguments no longer exist. I've been using the following to identify valid args `strings MediaCreationTool1909.exe | findstr /R "^/[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"`. Another approach would be (1) Download/mount oversized ISO (2) Export required editions from `install.wim`, using `/compress:recovery` (3) Repack ISO. This will definitely bring your ISO < 4.7GB. My 20H2 x64 ISO with Home + Pro is 4.63GB. Here's my notes: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xt4XxKgtkFU4sw0g5xXxbz7d57jS0lS2_JksXVJ_q9o

Comment: It looks like I was wrong and the command line arguments DO still exist in Win10 MCT. My method of extracting them was flawed. A more reliable way is to (1) launch the MCT (2) launch Process Explorer, elevated (3) locate the `SetupHost.exe` child process (child of e.g. `MediaCreationTool1909.exe`) (4) right-click this child process and left-click Properties (5) Go to the Strings tab and click the Save button to save all the strings to a file (6) Search this file for lines starting with `/`.